# Formal definition of $\Omega_{X/Y}\otimes k(x)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

For example on Hartshorne p.271, given a closed point $x$ of nonsingular varieties $X,Y$ over an algebraically closed field $k$. We have $k(x)\cong k$. And we can tensor $k(x)$ to get $\Omega_{X/Y}\otimes k(x)$. Here $\Omega_{X/Y}$ is a sheaf while $k(x)$ is a field. I wonder what the formal definition of $\Omega_{X/Y}\otimes k(x)$ is? To me it means at the stalk, it's the tensor product of the stalk of $\Omega_{X/Y}$ with $k(x)$, but what's the formal definition?